# How do i add activity within activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

i'm trying to make an app for nexus 7.
how can i display multiple activity to red area when the button is clicked??
Btn_A call activity A
Btn_B call activity B
Btn_C call activity C
Btn_D call activity D
i'm really need a example for this.

Comment: Look at this Links it may usefull.http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1160 and http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in this case.

You can find some useful examples in the [API demos](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Tab activity is the best for that scenario. Please read the below link for tab activity.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: TabActivity documentation says: "This class is deprecated.
New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT." I think it is more useful to learn up-to-date tools instead of deprecated ones.